# SQL subquery going heywire

Tags: mysql, subquery

I am trying to fetch some combined result from two separate individual tables.
The transaction_fact table has around 3.6 million rows and translation_table has around 300000 rows.
Now i want a sum of amount for all transactions grouped by location and the product within that location. But as the fact table has only location id and product id and i would like the names in the result , I am using sub query.

My query is as follows:

```
  SELECT 
       ( SELECT translation 
           FROM translation_table 
          WHERE dim_name LIKE 'location_dim' 
            AND lang_id LIKE 'es' 
            AND  dim_id LIKE CAST(o.loc_id AS CHAR(50)) 
            AND field_name LIKE 'city') AS Location
     , ( SELECT product_name 
           FROM prod_dim 
          WHERE prod_id = o.prod_id) AS Product
     , SUM(amount)
    FROM transaction_fact o 
   GROUP 
      BY loc_id
       , prod_id
   ORDER 
      BY loc_id
       , prod_id;
```

But this query is not returning anything , just keeps on processing.
I waited for about one and half hour but still no result.

Please tell me what might be going wrong.

Comment: This might be the strangest query I've seen in a while. If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: You should take a look at JOINs

Comment: The schema for tables and columns is given in comments of answer 1. And the desired result is total of transaction amount grouped over location and product... i.e. sum of total amount for all transactions for a product at one location...   Result table should have columns as : Location | Product |Total_amount

Answer (score 0):

Joining the tables should eliminate the need for subqueries and give some performance boost. If not you may need to provide more details on the table structure before we can help. Something like this should get you started:

```
SELECT t.translation AS Location, p.product_name AS Product, SUM(o.amount) AS Total
FROM transaction_fact o
  INNER JOIN translation_table t ON CAST(o.loc_id AS char(50)) = t.dim_id
  INNER JOIN prod_dim p ON p.prod_id = o.prod_id
WHERE t.dim_name = 'location_dim' 
            AND t.lang_id = 'es' 
            AND t.field_name = 'city'
GROUP BY t.translation, p.product_name
ORDER BY o.loc_id, o.prod_id;
```

Notes: I've changed the LIKEs to =, as LIKE is for when you want to match on a pattern that includes wildcards.

The CAST that is used in the join to translation_table is not ideal. If you could do away with that you'd get better performance.

Comment: LIKE also has a role to play in case sensitive collations.

Comment: Interesting, I did not know this. Thank you. OP, feel free to change back to LIKE if necessary.

Comment: Would it not create a join of about 3 lac * 3.6 million rows to filter from? because those tables we are joining has those  many rows respectively.

Comment: @Chris :** 'SELECT t.translation AS Location, p.product_name AS Product, SUM(o.amount) AS Total
FROM transaction_fact o
  INNER JOIN translation_table t ON CAST(o.loc_id AS char(50)) = t.dim_id
  INNER JOIN prod_dim p ON p.prod_id = o.prod_id
WHERE t.dim_name = 'location_dim' 
            AND t.lang_id = 'es' 
            AND t.field_name = 'city'
GROUP BY o.loc_id, o.prod_id
ORDER BY o.loc_id, o.prod_id;'**    Tried this code.. but still the same problem exists

Comment: Your solution may lie in indexing the tables better then, or there may be some additional criteria that should be taken into account in the join conditions, which would only be known if you can detail all of the columns in the tables involved. I'm afraid I don't know much about profiling or performance optimising in mysql.

Comment: Also it looks like the GROUP BY in the code in your comment may not be right, it should reference the columns in the SELECT that are not aggregated. Though that should error rather than take a long time. Note also as per my answer, the CAST won't help performance and it would be better to join on an int value rather than a string.

Comment: @ChrisFlynn :   transaction_fact : (cust_id, prod_id, amount, loc_id, paygate_id, date_id, transaction_time);                              Location_dim:(loc_id, area, city, country) ;                                      Product_dim:(prod_id, product_name, price) ;                              translation_table:(id, dim_name, dim_id, lang_id, field_name, translation)    ....   The translation table consists of translation for location dimension attributes which are city,area, and country and also translations for product dimension attribute which is product_name with help of all those columns.